# Ranking a column against other columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
     A_Bid   A_Ask    B_Bid   B_Ask   C_Bid   C_Ask   D_Bid   D_Ask ..  rank_bid
0    120.12  120.15   120.13  120.16  120.14  120.15  120.12  120.15     3
1    8.55    8.65      8.45   8.75    8.53    8.64    8.50     8.60      1
```

If I have a dataframe with axixes like the diagram above, how can I do a DataFrame.rank for each row horizontally- rather than vertically.

I would like to create a column called `'rank_bid'` at the end of the df and find `'A_Bid'` rank against `'B_Bid', 'C_Bid', 'D_Bid'`, etc...  I would also like to rank the `'ask'` but using the minimum value as the highest ranked.

Comment: Could you attach your expected result?

Comment: Just added some data, Anton

Comment: Can you explain, why value in first row is `3` and second `1`? Because function `df.rank` return `DataFrame` and you need `Series`.

Comment: I'm trying to find the rank of A_Bid's  '120.12' relative to '120.13', '120.14' and '120.12'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) your df to just the 'Bid' columns and call [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html#pandas.DataFrame.rank) on `axis=1` with `method='dense'` and `ascending=False`:

```
In [91]:
df['rank_bid'] = df.filter(like='Bid').rank(method='dense',axis=1, ascending=False)['A_Bid']
df

Out[91]:
    A_Bid   A_Ask   B_Bid   B_Ask   C_Bid   C_Ask   D_Bid   D_Ask  rank_bid
0  120.12  120.15  120.13  120.16  120.14  120.15  120.12  120.15     3
1    8.55    8.65    8.45    8.75    8.53    8.64    8.50    8.60     1
```

Here is the output from the `rank` method:

```
In [92]:
df.filter(like='Bid').rank(method='dense',axis=1, ascending=False)

Out[92]:
   A_Bid  B_Bid  C_Bid  D_Bid
0      3      2      1      3
1      1      4      2      3
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Only question is will this work for the ask? `df['Rank_ask'] =   df.filter(like='Ask').rank(method='dense',axis=1, ascending=True)['A_Ask']`.  I only ask, b/c when I tried it, I couldn't get my numbers to match.

Comment: Not sure what you expect, the output matches what I would expect

Comment: For instance, all of the rows were `A_Ask` is supposed to be ranked 1, it's ranked 2 instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce that I get `In [92]:

df.filter(like='Bid').rank(method='dense',axis=1, ascending=False)
df.filter(like='Bid').rank(method='dense',axis=1, ascending=False)
Out[92]:
   A_Bid  B_Bid  C_Bid  D_Bid
0      3      2      1      3
1      1      4      2      3`

Comment: The original one you wrote for the bid works great... I was talking about also trying to filter on the 'ASK' and ranking 'A_Ask'.  When I change the filter to `ask`, `ascending=True`, and rank to `['A_Ask']`- for some reason I'm off.

Comment: Sorry wrong copy paste: `In [95]:

df.filter(like='Ask').rank(method='dense',axis=1, ascending=True)
Out[95]:
   A_Ask  B_Ask  C_Ask  D_Ask
0      1      2      1      1
1      3      4      2      1` I seem to get correct results

Comment: I see, it assigns a rank of 2 if there are duplicate values.

Comment: Are you after `In [118]:

first
df.filter(like='Ask').rank(method='first',axis=1, ascending=True)
Out[118]:
   A_Ask  B_Ask  C_Ask  D_Ask
0      1      4      2      3
1      3      4      2      1`?